# How do you split a string in a cell after every nth word into rows

Tags: excel, vba, formula, user-defined-functions

How do you split a sentence after every nth word

Hi everyone,
I have a long string in cell B2 that I want to split into rows based on a variable number of words that is entered in cell D2.

My string in "B2" = "One two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen … …
"

My variable in "D2" is 4

My result for the first line/row is "One two three four"

So far I have used this formula in "F3":

```
=LEFT($B$2,FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE($B$2," ","*",$D$2))-1)
```

for the first line/row

I need to carry on splitting the string so that the final result would be:

> One two three four
>
> five six seven eight
>
> nine ten eleven twelve
>
> thirteen fourteen fifteen
>
> sixteen seventeen eighteen
>
> nineteen … …

each of the above resulting lines in its respective row.

I don't mind the type of solution formula UDF or sub. Your help is greatly appreciated.

[image: split a string after every nth word variable]

[image]

After using Davis' UDF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a UDF that would accomplish this for you.

```
Public Function SplitOnNth(ByVal inputStr$, ByVal StartPos&, ByVal NumWords&) As String

    Dim arr() As String, i As Long, newArr() As String
    arr = Split(inputStr)
    ReDim newArr(NumWords - 1)

    'Arrays are zero-based, but your string isn't. Subtract 1
    For i = StartPos - 1 To StartPos + NumWords - 2
        If i > UBound(arr) Then Exit For    'Exit if you loop past the last word in string
        newArr(i - StartPos + 1) = arr(i)
    Next

    SplitOnNth = Join(newArr, " ")

End Function
```

This places every word that is separated by a space into an array of words. It will loop through the array to reach you max size (`NumWords` argument), and output the string.

This UDF requires 3 arguments:

- `inputStr` *(String)*: The entire string that is being used for your split
- `StartPos` *(Long)*: The number of the first word you want to start with. In your case, `1` would start with the word **One**
- `NumWords` *(Long)*: THe total words, including the one from `StartPos`, to include in your function's output.

The formula you would use for your first line that you show in your example would look like:

```
=SplitOnNth($B$2, 1, 4)
```

*- OR -*

```
=SplitOnNth($B$2, $E3 * $D$2 - $D$2 + 1, $D$2)
```

Which would result in the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. The UDF works great except for the last row when the total number left for split is less than four. I get #VALUE! instead of seventeen which is the last word from the string

Comment: I had made a few adjustments to the code after my initial post. You may have copied the old one. Does the one you are using contain the line `If i > Ubound(arr) Then Exit For`? This line was designed for this purpose.

Comment: My mistake I didn't realise that change. The UDF works flawlessly. Thank you very much, 5 stars x 2.

Comment: Using the same UDF is it possible to ignore counting words that are in between parentheses but still have them printed in the rows. So if my string = "One two three four (1) five six seven eight nine ten (2) eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen (3)"; the result should be exactly the same as in Davis's solution 4 words in each row/line and if any parentheses then these should be included as extra.   Result should be:
row1:
One two three four
row2:
(1) five six seven eight
row3:
nine ten (2) eleven twelve
---
row5:
(3) seventeen (4)

Comment: Does this same function work in google spreadsheets? 
I see the error: Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula.
I have capitalized function name at two places as for forced capitalization requirement.